# OpenPyXl: Can I reference data from one Excel file and insert values into a cell based on an identifier?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is it possible to get the SKUs — and other information — from one Excel file and reference it in another below an identifier: SKU, Name, etc.?

I have one Excel file with various sheets which acts like a template. In each sheet the same, or very similar, identifiers are found e.g. `Product SKU`.

My current idea is that once I have the `cell.column` and `cell.row` for `Product SKU` I can store that in variable, respectively, and increment the `cell.row` by `+1` so I can load the information from another sheet below `Product SKU`. The end result would look like this in Excel. I would apply the logic above to all other information I want to load.

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Product Sku | Product Name   |
+-------------+----------------+
| 12345678    | Some Product   |
+-------------+----------------+
```

The idea I am trying to produce. If there is a better way, please do let me know.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = "product_import_tmp.xlsx")
inventory_1_sheet = wb["Inventory 1"]

for row in inventory_1_sheet.iter_rows(values_only=False):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Product SKU":
            sku_y = cell.column
            sku_x = cell.row + 1  # The Product SKU information would go here
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide what your excel files look like.
I would suggest pandas instead of openpyxl if there is complex manipulation to excel.